# Pass a parameter with JUnitCore.run() method

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have one Test launcher class to run different type of tests by loading and executing classes generated to run with selenium. In this I am launching test by giving a string name and then running it with JUnitCore.run() method

Here is sample code for that:

```
Class clsTestStep = Class.forName("CheckLogin",true,new ClassLoader() {});

JUnitCore  junit = new JUnitCore();

junit.addListener(new ExecutionListener());

org.junit.runner.Result runner= junit.run(clsTestStep);
```

Can Anyone tell me if I want to pass some object or property value with this class then How can I achieve it?

Note that I want that object to be available in '*CheckLogin*' class at test running time, i.e username/password passed from *launcher* class to '*CheckLogin*' class.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same requirement.